# implement Ant colony optimization on VRP

Tags: dijkstra, backtracking

I am trying to implement Ant colony optimization problem on Veichle routing problem can I use dijkstra algorithm in such a problem by replacing the cost with the propability or it is a wrong approach. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information. What do you need us to help you with?

Comment: VRP basically want to deliver amout of good to set of customers each veichle has capacity and have a set of customer to serve we have many veichle so I want to satisfy every customer need with minumum cost . to reach to one customer can I use dijkstra

Comment: VRP veichle that have many customers to serve with least cost I need to use ACO for that so I will replace the cost with the propability of ACO.my approach is to use dijkstra to each customer and the last one will be my source

Comment: I think what you want is to find distances between each pair of nodes? Dijkstra is used for solving paths from single source to all other nodes. But there are dynamic programming approaches that you can use to find the distances between all the pairs as is required in ant colony optimization. You can check out this question for algorithms. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668702/shortest-distance-between-all-pairs-of-nodes-in-graph